# How do I properly set the state to a response output in React using Typescript?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hooks

I'm new to React and I'm sure this is a very simple solution. However, I can't seem to figure out how to properly set the state of a component to be the response from a REST call I make.

Here's the response object format I'm returning

```
export interface CoinMarketChartsAll {
   oneDay: Array<CoinChartDataMapped>;
   sevenDay: Array<CoinChartDataMapped>;
   oneMonth: Array<CoinChartDataMapped>;
}
```

And here's my functional component where I fetch this data and try to set the state equal to it

```
const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);
const [cryptoData, setCryptoData] = useState<CoinMarketChartsAll>();

useEffect(() => {
    fetchMarketChart();
}, []);

const fetchMarketChart = async () => {
    setLoading(true);
    if (!cryptoData) {
        getCoinMarketChart('lgcy-network').then((response) => {
            setCryptoData(response);
            setLoading(false);
        })
            .catch((error) => {
                console.log(error);
                setLoading(false);
            });
    }
}
```

I tried logging the output inside the if statement and cryptoData was always equal to undefined. Until I toggled the if statement to be

```
if (cryptoData) {
```

Then it would load it into the state, but when I reloaded the page it would never make it into the if statement. Can anyone please point out what I'm doing wrong? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I tried logging the output inside the if statement and cryptoData was always equal to undefined.

That is simply because the state setter takes effect after a "tick": you can do `setCryptoData(true)`, but `cryptoData` will remain `undefined` until that next tick.

> when I reloaded the page it would never make it into the if statement

When you first changed your `if` condition, React Hot Module swap kicked in and updated your component, *while preserving its current state*, therefore your `cryptoData` state was already truthy.

But after page reload, you get a "fresh" component instance, which starts with a freshly initialized state, i.e. with `undefined` value, since you define it with no initial value (`useState<CoinMarketChartsAll>(/* no initial value */)`)